# Force <input type="submit"> inside <form> element to subit in same tab/window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a `<form>` as

```
<!-- pseudocode -->
<form action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="class" id="id" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

If i click the `<input>` element with the mouse wheel or ctrl + click it etc, it opens in a new tab/window, and I cannot allow that since the data will have two states in the application/client, worst case scenario (if it's not possible) I would like to force the current window to navigate to the same place as the new window without submitting the form again (that is, if the client just submitted the form) without going into complicated $_SESSION management from the server.

Kindly I **do not** want to use AJAX for this.

Comment: If you don't need to go to the new page, why not just use javascript to prevent the default behavior of the button, and submit the data via AJAX? You could then update the page based on the response.

Comment: First off, it doesn't clearly say that. It states that you are doing that (not clearly), but that doesn't mean you **need** to. Secondly, no code is unmaintainable if it's done correctly. And lastly, you can disable the ctrl key (and any other key if you want, along with right clicking) if you want to. The answer is below. The BEST way for this, is to use AJAX, and it's not difficult if you're not scared of it.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click using the following code:

```
$("#submit-btn-id").click(function (e) {
  // If there's a ctrl key pressed while clicking, please stop the event.
  if (e.ctrlKey)
    return false;
});
```

Or the better way is to use AJAX. You can bind an AJAX function on the `form`'s submit event:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post("action.php", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the action from your form tag it will take the

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

you can do it like this

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="class" id="id" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

or you can do it like this

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="class" id="id" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_id').submit(function() {
         $.ajax({
             url: 'your_page.php // and if it this page just put it's name.php',
             data: {field1: value1, field2: value2},
             type: 'post',
             dataType: 'json',
             beforeSend: function() {
                 // do something like show the loading,,,
             },
             success: function() {
                 // do something after the request has status of 200,,,
             },
             error: function() {
                 // do something if the request has error like 400, 500 server internal error/ page not found etc,,,
             },
             complete: function() {
                 // do something finish,,,
             },
         });
         return false;
    });
});
```